# Convergence, Set Inclusion and Indicator Function

Tags: probability-theory

In the textbook I am learning Probability from I read the following: "Given the $\sigma-$algebra $\mathcal{A}$ defined on $\Omega$, we can say that $A_n \in \mathcal{A} $ converges to $A$ if lim$_{n \to \infty } 1_{A_n}=1_A, \, \forall \,\, \omega \in \Omega "$.

- Does the definition means that $A_n$ increases, i.e. $A_n \subset A_{n+1},$ (or eventually decreases, i.e. $A_{n+1} \subset A_n$) to $A$, or is it meant a more general setting?
- Why is lim$_{n \to \infty } 1_{A_n}=1_A, \, \forall \,\, \omega \in \Omega, \,$ equivalent to $A=$ lim sup $A_n=$ lim inf $A_n$ (according to the book) ?

I will highly appreciate your help.